# How do I enable bridged networking in Xen guest?

Tags: virtual-machine, yocto, configure, xen

I am running `Xen 4.9` and adding a yocto guest.

I got it to startup with basic config:

```
name="yoctoguest"
builder="hvm"
kernel="/usr/lib/xen-4.9/boot/hvmloader"
memory=128
disk=[...]
```

but now I added:

```
vif=['bridge=xenbr0']
serial='pty'
```

and get errors:

```
libxl:error:libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-bridge online [29260] exited with error status 1
```

also ... `script: Could not find bridge device xenbr0`

This is my `netplan` file:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s31f5:
            dhcp: false
    version: 2
    bridges:
        xenbr0:
            interfaces: [enp0s31f5]
            dhcp: true
```

What am I missing in order to enable bridged networking in this guest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using command:

> netplan generate

followed by

> netplan apply

was what I was missing at the time.

This worked to get the netplan started again - I had not re-generated the netplan config.